# SQL update query for comma separated string with distinct values in one column

Tags: sql, sql-update

I want to update a column string value with distinct values in a SQL update query.

I have a table 'Data' with a column 'Channel' with value `4,7` as follows:

| Channel |
| --- |
| 4,7 |

I want to update this column value if a distinct value comes, like 8. Then it should update:

| Channel |
| --- |
| 4,7,8 |

And if value 7 comes then it should not update as I want distinct values.

How can I write such a SQL query?

```
select Channel = STUFF(
    (SELECT distinct ',' + x.channel
      FROM Data AS x     
      FOR XML PATH(''), 
      TYPE).value(N'./text()[1]', N'varchar(max)'), 
      1, 1, '')
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help immensely.

Comment: And add a tag for the dbms you're using.

Comment: Instead of having one row containing `4,7` you should have two rows, one containing `4` and the other containing `7`. If `8` comes you should insert another row containing `8`.

Comment: Agreed, you need to normalize this out into another table `DataChannel (DataId, ChannelId)`